# SSIS Don't fail Agent Job on Script Task Failure

Tags: ssis

I have the below in SSIS. The scrip task, 'Call PS - does the log file exist and is it locked' can by design fail and then it waits (via Script - Wait before retry) and retries via the Loop RetryMax times. However, if I run via a SQL Agent job and it fails then the job only goes through the loop once and then fails the whole job. If I execute interactively in Visual Studio it can loop up to 10 times and works. Is there a setting I am missing so the loop will run more than once when executed via an Agent Job? If it helps, I have to add a blank OnError event handler to the ''Call PS - does the log file exist and is it locked' and change the system variable Propagate to False. Could the agent job be not 'seeing this?'

[image]

Comment: On the Script Task, try setting the FailPackageOnFailure/FailParentOnFailure properties to false.

Comment: tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your loop and the properties of "Call PS" task, set the MaximumErrorCount to something greater then 1.

[image]

EDIT --
To view Execution Report:
Drill into Integration Services Catalog >> SSIDB >> [Project Name] >> [Package Name]

Right click the package name and follow the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Job still fails at agent level I'm afraid.

Comment: What does your execution report show for the failure?

Comment: Do you mean in the SQL job agent history?

Comment: Drill into your Integrations Services Catalogs to the package level and then right click it and you should be able to get more detailed info on the failure cause.

Comment: Its using FileSystem not Catalogs.  I think I'm going to change it to output as True or False but always make the 'Call PS...' successful